# Network Status in C

Tags: c, networking

Right now I am able to retrieve the network status using the following code..

```
 popen("netstat -i | grep '^e[a-z][a-z]*0[ \t]' | head -n1","r")


sscanf(line,"%32s %d %*s %*s %d %d %d %d",
               name, &mtu,
               &in_packets, &in_errors,
               &out_packets, &out_errors);
```

I want to calculate packets per sec.. How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: From that information, you can't.

Comment: what is that line coming from?

Comment: im getting the time using `time = time(NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to calculate packets/second

1. Get the number of packets right now.
2. Wait *n* seconds.
3. Get the new number of packets.

Now subtract the first number from the second number and divide by *n* and you have your packets/second over a given interval.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [tcpstat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpstat) e.g.

```
tcpstat -i eth0 -o '%b\n'
```

**Output**

```
16516.80   #bps
```